# Is it possible to color the fontawesome icon colors?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I can change fontcolor, but not the "fill". I first tried setting background-color, but that fills the whole icon box area.

For example, I have

```
<i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"></i>
```

but I want it to be yellow.

Edit:
The use case is that I want a "favorite" icon to be outline of grey, on click, the outline becomes orange, fill to yellow.

Comment: you can now do this easely with font-awesome 5 and transforms. Two stars on top of eachother

Comment: The latest versions (5+) of Fontawesome have released Solid and Regular versions of stars. Solid will display a filled star and Regular will display an Empty star.
`<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>`
`<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Font-awesome comes with a number of both outlined and filled [icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/). **The [star](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star/) is one of them**.

There are four different star icon classes that you can use:

```
class="icon-star"
class="icon-star-empty"
class="icon-star-half"
class="icon-star-half-empty"
```

If you're a glass-half-full type of person, you can also use the alias for 'icon-star-half-empty':

```
class="icon-star-half-full"
```

You can colour the font-awesome icons and use different effects to achieve what you're looking for:

```
<i class="icon-star-empty icon-large icon-a"></i><br><br>
<i class="icon-star-empty icon-large icon-b"></i><br><br>
<i class="icon-star icon-large icon-c"></i> or <i class="icon-star icon-large icon-d"></i>
```

Where the following CSS is used (rather than using inline styles):

```
.icon-a {
    color: #888;
} 
.icon-b {
    color: orange;
}
.icon-c {
    color: yellow;
}
.icon-d {
    color: yellow;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: orange;
}
```

You can also substitute/set the size too, if you don't want to use `icon-large`.

The above code outputs the following:

[image]

but I've put the above code and a few more options in a JSFiddle, which you [can look at here](http://jsfiddle.net/wbxhZ/).

It's also possible to use [css-transitions](/questions/tagged/css-transitions) that provides a way to animate changes to CSS properties instead of having the changes take effect instantly and or in combination with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: @jqed You're welcome. A working example (that you can fiddle with) in addition to a description is often worth a thousand words or few blocks of code.

Comment: Just to point it out, the latest option using the `-webkit-text-stroke-width` will only work for Chrome.

Comment: Confirmed, stroke color does not work in Firefox 44.

Comment: Putting a stroke-width and stroke-color of black with a white color effectively makes the icon view-able on any background. Very nice if you need to overlay the icon on user images.

Comment: The latest versions (5+) of Fontawesome have released Solid and Regular versions of stars. Solid will display a filled star and Regular will display an Empty star.
`<i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>`
`<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>`

Answer (score 12):

All you need is to set `color: yellow`. Because the icons are a font, they will take whatever colour you'd set to any other font (text) in the same way.

if you want to fill the whole star as yellow, try icon-star instead of icon-star-empty

you can try this

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: orange;
```

to add stroke (outline) to the font itself. I hope thats what you are looking for.

and to fill it just use the normal

```
color: yellow;
```

Comment: good answer, I had to give it to @nickhar though for the jsfiddle inclusion. thx for coming back.

Answer (score 7):

If you came here like I did wanting a way to have a separate "fill" color for an icon than the font color (for example, the "F" of the Facebook icon is transparent and shows whatever the background is below it), here's your answer:

```
<p class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x fa-2x fa-inverse"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-stack-2x fa-2x"></i>
</p>
```

You take the regular rounded square and stack it under the icon you want visible. If you want it to be white, you can specify `fa-inverse` assuming your default is black. [More info here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked).

Comment: Good call @Brynn!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with "-webkit-text-stroke" is that is not fully supported by FF and IE, so what I do in this case is to use the half star in a pseudo class inside of the normal star, something like this:

```
.icon-star.red-border {
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.icon-star.red-border:after {
    content: "\f006";
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;    
}
```

And works for me, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdgr537y/)

Thanks.

Comment: please update, doesn't work for latest version of font awesome which has `.fa` class

Answer (score 1):

Extending to the above answers, sometimes you want to add stroke/border to the font/icon. In that case the following is presented.

At least in WebKit. Example:

```
h1 {
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

Or shorthand:

```
h1 {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

The stroke works in WebKit but disappears in other browsers! Alternative?
We can use the text-shadow property and simulate a stroke.

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
}
```

We use four shadows, each 1px offset of black with no spread, one each to the top right, top left, bottom left, and bottom right.

The only holdout would be IE9 and down, which of course you can use IE specific CSS to account for.

P.S. For my own reference as well.

Source: [Link](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this with very simple CSS using only a single font-awesome icon. These icons are rendered as an SVG.

How it works is I'm using the solid/filled icon but turning it white and adding a black border to make it look empty. Upon clicking it, I can toggle the .fill class to change the color to gold, making it solid.

HTML:

```
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-star {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 30px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-star.fill {
     color: #ffd700 /* gold */
}
```

JS for toggle using jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', ".fa-star", function () {
     favorite(this);
});

function favorite(item) {
     $(item).toggleClass("fill");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use, `reactjs` and under components

```
<i className="icon-star-empty icon-large" style={{color: "grey", fontSize: "70px"}}></i>
```