# Is there a way I can change a font awesome symbol to just show the outline only?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using this:

```
<span class='fa fa-fw fa-stop'></span>
```

But it shows a very big square. Does anyone know if it possible to make it show just the outline of the square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the icons which are provided as outline only have an additional -o in the name e.g: [fa-arrow-circle-o-left](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/arrow-circle-o-left/) - the stop icon doesn't have that option.

You could use the `fa-square-o` which is: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/square-o/ which would achieve what you need - but it's not specifically the stop icon but just outlined.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is given here, which can be used for all font-awesome icons:
[Is it possible to color the fontawesome icon colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540383/is-it-possible-to-color-the-fontawesome-icon-colors)

The css looks like this:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #666;
color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either use fa-square-o, or you could use fa-stop and using CSS color and border rules to achieve the effect for a box with no rounded corners.

Here is a link:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mcddx2q/

```
.fa {
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Or you could search for an outlined box in another set of font icons that is not font-awesome, thereare a few on bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the webkit-based solutions is that they'll only work in webkit browsers.  A slightly more portable solution would be to set the color of the icon to the same as the background (or transparent) and use text-shadow to create an outline:

```
.fa-outline-dark-gray {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #999,
            1px -1px 0 #999,
           -1px 1px 0 #999,
            1px 1px 0 #999;
}
```

It doesn't work in ie <10, but at least it's not restricted to webkit browsers.

Answer (score 3):

For people coming across this in the future: I was solving a similar problem and came up with a tangential solution that may work depending on your scenario and the specific icon. I had a blue background and wanted a white checkmark outline, with the blue inside preserved. What I ended up doing was creating two checkmark icons- one that was white, and another that was blue but slightly smaller. I then used css to position the blue checkmark inside of the white one which achieved the desired effect. It may take some fiddling and it may not work for all use cases, but it worked for me in mine.